# Hiding xp:mesages box when empty

Tags: xpages

In my Xpages application I am using Bootstrap for theming. I have a xp:messages box that I have applied some Bootstrap CSS to.

When then are no messages I want to hide the panel that contains the messages. So I came up with the following:

```
<xp:panel rendered="#{javascript:facesContext.getMessages().hasNext()}"                 styleClass="alert alert-info">
<xp:text escape="true" value="#{javascript:facesContext.getMessages().hasNext()}">
</xp:text>
<xp:messages globalOnly="true" layout="list"></xp:messages>
</xp:panel>
```

However I notice sometimes the xp:messages control is empty but facesContext.getMessages().hasNext() returns true.

Is there another way to check the value of xp:messages? I tried getComponent(...).getValue() but than the application breaks.

This is what is returned to the browser:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
<span>true</span><span role="alert"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to directly apply the bootstrap class to the xp:messages control? e.g.

```
<xp:messages id="messages1" infoClass="alert alert-info"></xp:messages>
```

hereby you do not need the surrounding panel and compute the rendered property

Comment: Thank you! I notice I can remove the surrounding panel control and can skip calling the hasMessages method.

Answer (score 3):

I write based on your example code, that is, you want to deal with global messages only. It's important that you pass a `null` value to the getMessages `method`. In that way you will be filtering for the global messages only or, in other words, messages that are not tied to a specific component.

All messages: `facesContext.getMessages()`

Global messages only: `facesContext.getMessages(null)`

Messages for specific component: `facesContext.getMessages('whateverIdYouHave')`

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap that call into a function you keep in a SSJS library and use something like `rendered=JavaScript:hasMessages()` That makes is easier to understand the code later.

Inside the function you should be able to either iterate over the messages and check if they are empty (or eventually: messages you don’t care about it).

The JSF spec has `getMessageList()` that returns a Collection you can check with `isEmpty()`. Not sure if it has been implemented in XPages. Paul, as usual, has more info here:

http://www.intec.co.uk/how-many-xpages-errors-have-i-got/

The counter seems most reliable

Comment: Not for the first time, I'd completely forgotten I'd written that blog post! It sounds like the problem may be that there are some messages associated to a specific component. So they don't display in the `globalOnly` messages panel, but exist in `hasNext()`. Looking at the spec in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessages(java.lang.String), facesContext.getMessages()` has an overloaded method that takes an ID. So if you pass an ID for a component like the top level XPage or a View Panel,it should get only global ones (none for that component exist)